# Why is PHP Mcrypt returning post message garbage?

Tags: php, c++, mcrypt, crypto++

Using the same (basic) code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187689/crypto-to-php-mcrypt-not-working/) but switching to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, I'm now getting the correct data out of php mcrypt_decrypt, except in certain circumstances, it's padding out the end of my message a newline with seemingly random binary characters.

The following, for example, came back from a request to decrypt:

```
{"messageData":{"identity":"test","msg_id":0,"token":"fakeToken58586"},"messageName":"fetchSavedData_request"}\n\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b
```

I would think this is a padding issue, but even if I pad out my string to the correct length, I occasionally get garbage, and strings that would normally need to be padded, do occasionally come back correct.

What's going on here?

Comment: Code that's sending to mcrypt is done through crypto++.

Comment: I've seen this before in the manual I think; the decoded string is not always right padded with only \0 ... are you using the latest php version? http://au2.php.net/mdecrypt_generic

Comment: Hard to say unfortunately. I grabbed the php5-mcrypt package for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jack pointed out in the comments, this is apparently a common problem. The code [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mdecrypt-generic.php#107979) works to remove control characters at the end of encrypted data.

Reproduced here for posterity:

```
$data = preg_replace( "/\p{Cc}*$/u", "", $data);
```